# SQL Oracle - how to find the final value for the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+
|  Name   | Name_Change |  Status   |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| Rick    | Brandon     | Cancelled |
| Brenda  | Alexa       | Active    |
| Brandon | TJ          | Cancelled |
| TJ      | Jonathan    | Active    |
| Randy   |             | Active    |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

So Rick --> Brandon --> TJ --> Jonathan

So my output should be:

```
+------+------------+--------+
| Name | Final Name | Status |
+------+------------+--------+
| Rick | Jonathan   | Active |
+------+------------+--------+
```

How do I code this on SQL?

TIA

Comment: The order you perceive in your sample data is not really there unless you have another column which provides this ordering.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah the updates in the "name" information are in the same table. So I cannot do a reiterative join until the Status is Active?

Comment: This is a simple recursive query, search for *hierarchy recursive*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE, as in:

```
with
n (name, name_change, status, version) as (
  select t.*, 1 from t where name = 'Rick'
 union all
  select n.name, t.name_change, t.status, n.version + 1
  from n
  join t on t.name = n.name_change
)
select *
from n
where version = (select max(version) from n);
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd3d7/7).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of **Hierarchical Query** which starts with the member `Name = 'Rick'`. Filter out the records by using `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` pseudocolumn as  `WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` in order to have the topmost(e.g. *deepest* or *leaf*) element. Btw, it's possible to derive the whole path after starting member(`Rick`) by using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH()` function, and derive the `Name` depending on the shortest hierarchy path returning from this function. Therefore, use

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT MAX(Name) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST 
                         ORDER BY LENGTH(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name_Change, ' ->')) )
                         OVER () AS "Name",
        SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name_Change, ' ->') AS "Hierarchy Path",
        Name_Change AS "Final Name", 
        Status AS "Status",
        CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS cbi
   FROM tab t
  START WITH Name = 'Rick'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Name_Change = Name
)
SELECT "Name", "Hierarchy Path", "Final Name", "Status"
  FROM t
 WHERE cbi = 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cad6bb80f069fce8d0321017681351d0)</kbd>